# MVC Razor, displaying displaying data in certain order

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC View where I need to display DATA in a certain format, example below is in alphabetic with a numerical value tied to that letter.  It needs to be Top Down, split into 2 different columns.  As shown in the image attached it is alphabetic going down, then when half way through it needs to start on the next column, row 1.

[image]

This will be in a partial view and be used with several different result sets.  Definitely cannot hard code.

I dont have any code right now as I could either use either a table or just some Spans.  Open to suggestions.

I've thought of splitting the array in half, then just looping through each array item by item but wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your HTML structure (difficult to tell as you haven't shown it), you could possibly use css `column-count`:

```
.yourElement
{
    column-count:2;
}
```

Other than that, splitting the array in half is not such a bad idea, i suppose it depends on the length.

Comment: I just updated my original question to mention it has yet to be coded.